# How can match ids to names from different tables in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

```
A. event_choices

event_id | res_id | 
4        | 10     | 

B. restaurants 

res_id     | res_name | 
10         | xyz      | 

C. event
event_id   | event_name | 
4          | birthday   |
```

I've been trying inner join to try match the names to id but been unsuccessful

```
select event_id as id from event_choices inner join restaurants on res_id.id = res_name
```

any help would be greatly appreciated, very new to php/mysql

Comment: What data are you trying to get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT event.event_name, restaurants.res_name FROM event_choices 
    INNER JOIN restaurants ON event_choices.res_id = restaurants.res_id
    INNER JOIN event ON event_choices.event_id = event.event_id
```

could work.

If you select `*` instead of `event.event_name` you should get all data and be able to pick from it. You can also select specific fields in the form of `<table>.<field>`.

EDIT: added `res_name`

Comment: would be great to get the event_name and the res_name in the results

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
SELECT event_id, res_name FROM event_choices, restaurants WHERE event_choices.res_id = restaurants.res_id
```

Enjoy ^_^

Comment: This is great how can I modify this to match the event_id to event_name ?

Comment: @Grundizer: Just join `event` in there too.  `WHERE event.event_id = event_choices.event_id`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  select ec.event_id as id from event_choices ec inner join restaurants r on ec.res_id = r.res_id
```